# async x await x Future

Tags: flutter, dart

Para que servem as keywords `async` e `await` no Flutter?

**Algumas dúvidas que tenho são:**

**1 -** Elas pertencem ao Flutter ou ao Dart?

**2 -** Porque colocar o `async` no final do seguinte método?

```
 void _method(TodoItem item) async { }
```

**3 -** Porque colocar o `await` no inicio da chamada do seguinte método?

```
_results = await DB.query(TodoItem.table);
```

**4 -** Qual diferença entre `async` e `await`?

**5 -** Onde o `Future` entra no meio disso tudo?

Comment: Caramba, esse site é só para profissional!? Peguem leve, parece já vão negativando e votando para fechar sem mesmo ler a pergunta

Comment: @rubStackOverflow ontem teve um discussão sobre isso que tu comentou em uma outra pergunta hahahaha Ta difícil, principalmente a tag Flutter (Parece ser uma tag problema), ta certo que muitas perguntas de Flutter a galera nem se da ao luxo de entender como se fazer uma pergunta aqui, mas não acho válido saírem dando downvote em todas... Ainda mais essa que agrega conhecimento ao site (Como dizem que deve ser).

Comment: @MatheusRibeiro eu vi, `downvote` está banalizado.

Answer (score 8):

Dart, assim como outras linguagens, trabalha com funções síncronas e assíncronas.

Explicarei de uma forma mais grosseira, mas ai você pesquisa mais sobre:

> **Função Síncrona**
>
> `bool tarefaFinalizada() => tarefas[0].finalizada == true;`
>
> É uma função que quando a execução do seu sistema chegar nela, ele esperará tudo que estiver dentro dela ser executada, para continuar fazendo o que precisa.
>
> **Função Assíncrona**
>
> `Future<bool> getTarefas() async => await http.get('tarefas');`
>
> É uma função que o sistema executa, mas não espera seu término, ele executa esta função e continua fazendo o que precisa.

Ou seja, a função síncrona, você espera a resposta da sua função para executar determinada ação.

**Future**

*Essa função vai retornar um dado do futuro ~~Cuidado com a Skynet*

Quando você usa funções assíncronas, você utiliza o `Future` para indicar que aquela função é assíncrona, ou melhor, que ela vai retornar um valor no "futuro", como por exemplo, vai retornar os valores daqui 5 segundos.

**await** *(Traduzindo pra BR -> "Aguarde")*

*Espere aqui até que a função termine e pegue o resultado dela.*

Você utiliza o `await` quando faz chamada que retornem um `future`. Isso faz com que o sistema espere a chamada da função assíncrona terminar para que execute o resto das coisas. Ou seja, transforma uma função assíncrona em síncrona.
Sempre que utilizar uma função que retorne um `Future` você terá que, em algum momento, adicionar o `await` para receber o valor correto, caso contrário irá receber sempre um `Future<SeuTipo>`.

**async**

*Essa função é assíncrona e em algum momento dela talvez eu precise esperar para pegar algum dado.*

Você precisa usar o `async` nas funções onde você vai utilizar o `await` para indicar que o método vai lidar com funções assíncronas de forma síncrona.

Você pode ler um pouco mais aqui nesses links:

- [Asynchronous programming: futures, async,
  await](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await) *(Em inglês)*
- [When to use async, await, then and Future in
  Dart?](https://medium.com/@jelenaaa.lecic/when-to-use-async-await-then-and-future-in-dart-5e00e64ab9b1)
  *(Em inglês)*

> Meu conselho...
>
> Estude mais sobre programação e principalmente estude mais sobre a
> linguagem Dart e o framework Flutter!
>
> Flutter é sim um framework rápido e prático, mas para quem já entende um pouco sobre programação. É melhor começar já entendendo bem e fazendo as coisas corretamente, do que ir remendando na medida que aprende... Então treine, faça testes, LEIA sempre a documentação do Flutter que é muito bem feita e organizada.

Answer (score -2):

> Sempre que utilizar uma função que retorne um Future você terá que, em algum momento, adicionar o await

Isso está incorreto, a utilização de uma instância que retorna o valor Future não implica na necessidade de utilização posterior do await.

Comment: Seja bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português. Por favor, não utilize o campo de respostas para fazer comentários sobre outra resposta; para isso você pode utilizar o próprio campo de comentários na resposta.