# Dart/Flutter: como usar retorno de um método em outro método? ambos invocados no Construtor da Classe

Tags: listview, flutter, return, construtor, assincronismo

Estou usando Dart/Flutter para desenvolver um aplicativo e nele tenho dois métodos Listeners do Firebase, conforme exibido abaixo, e gostaria de saber como, no método construtor, disparo um dos métodos somente depois do primeiro já ter populado as variáveis necessárias.

Classe e seu construtor:

```
class ItineraryBloc extends ChangeNotifier {
  ItineraryBloc() {
    // aqui irão as chamadas dos métodos citados acima...
  }


  List<Localidade> _listLocales = [];
  List<Veiculo> _listVehicles = [];
  String _selectedLocaleId = '';

...
```

1º método:

```
    // LISTENER DAS LOCALIDADES CADASTRADAS
  Future<List<Localidade>> getListAllLocales() async {
    _db.collection('localidades').orderBy('nome').snapshots().listen((snapshot) {
      listLocales = snapshot.docs.map((e) => Localidade.fromDocument(e)).toList();
      selectedLocaleId = listLocales.firstWhere((item) => item.sedeRegional == true).id;
      notifyListeners();
    });
    return listLocales;
  }
```

2° método:

```
// LISTENER DOS VEÍCULOS CADASTRADOS POR LOCALIDADES
  Future<List<Veiculo>> getListAllVehiclesByLocale() async {
    _db.collection('veiculos').where('idLocalidade', isEqualTo: selectedLocaleId).orderBy('placa').snapshots().listen((qSnap) {
      if (qSnap.docs.isNotEmpty) {
        listVehicles = qSnap.docs.map((v) => Veiculo.fromDocument(v)).toList();
        selectedVehicle = listVehicles[0];
      } else {
        listVehicles = [];
      }

      notifyListeners();
    });
    return listVehicles;
  }
}
```

O método `getListAllVehiclesByLocale` depende da variável `selectedLocaleId` que é setada no método `getListAllLocales`.

Minha ideia é chamar estes dois métodos no contrutor da classe para que sejam populadas as listas e variáveis afins para somente então eu utilizá-las em um widget. No entanto, o widget precisa exibir um feedback de carregamento/processamento dessas listar para então exibí-los em seus respectivos `PagesView` e `ListView.`

Answer (score 0):

> e gostaria de saber como, no método construtor, disparo um dos métodos somente depois do primeiro já ter populado as variáveis necessárias.

Em Dart, existe a palavra chave `await`.

Esse comando é usado para aguardar o término de uma função assíncrona para só então prosseguir com o que depender dela, sem bloquear a execução de seu programa.

Sem ela, você precisaria criar *callbacks* entre seus Futures, só que isso dificulta a leitura de código e fica mais confuso (menos linear). Seria algo do tipo:

```
getListAllLocales().then((retornoDaPrimeiraFuncao) => getListAllVehiclesByLocale());
```

Suas funções já retornam como um `Future`. Se você deseja aprender mais sobre assincronismo e Future/Await, existe esse ótimo [*codelab*](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await) que ensina os conceitos (em inglês).

Então, para utilizar o `await` que é [recomendado](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#prefer-asyncawait-over-using-raw-futures) pela linguagem, simplesmente coloque o await antes da chamada da função:

```
await getListAllLocales();
await getListAllVehiclesByLocale();
```

Você não pode usar `await` em uma função que não está marcada como assíncrona (`async`), e você não pode marcar um construtor como assíncrono. Então uma solução é criar um método assíncrono e no construtor o chamar sem `await`:

```
Future futuroASerMonitorado;
ItineraryBloc() {
    futuroASerMonitorado= FuncaoAssincrona();
  }
void FuncaoAssincrona ()async{
    await getListAllLocales();
    await getListAllVehiclesByLocale();
  }
```

> No entanto, o widget precisa exibir um feedback de carregamento/processamento dessas listar para então exibí-los em seus respectivos PagesView e ListView.

Um Widget perfeito para este caso é o [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html). Você fornece um Future a ele, e ele se constrói baseado no estado desse Future. No seu caso, um exemplo simples seria:

```
return FutureBuilder(
    future: futuroASerMonitorado,
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {   
      if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
          return  Center(child: Text('Carregando...'));
      }else{
          if (snapshot.hasError)
            return Center(child: Text('Erro: ${snapshot.error}'));
          else
            return ListView(); //Aqui você tem a certeza que o Futuro completou e pode acessar o retorno dele com snapshot.data
      }
    },
  );
```

Comment: Mesmo implementando suas sugestões, @Naslausky, o retorno ainda está incorreto (vide imagem: http://prntscr.com/v2hwgd ). Pois, retornam as variáveis vazias quando carregado a Classe. Deveriam estar setadas, uma vez que, os prints ocorrem após os "awaits" dos métodos em questão. Não tenho tido sucesso nssa questão.

Comment: Não. Você colocando o _print_ após a chamada de uma função assíncrona que não tem o await, ele vai printar sem aguardar as funções terminarem. Experimente colocar o print dentro da função ```loadLocalesAndVehiclesLists``` e você verá o que digo. Sugiro você dar uma lida no _codelabs_ que linkei na resposta, para melhor entender essa parte, ou fazer outra pergunta aqui no site.

Comment: @Milhomens [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/447627/152025) você pode ver uma resposta em português sobre o assunto também.