# Chamada do firestore retornando antes do fim da execução, no flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firestore

Eu tenho uma função pra fazer a busca dos dados no firestore.
Chamo a função que fica numa classe controladora helper.getTodosAgendamentos(); Funciona bem.

Abaixo um trecho da minha função de busca no firestore.

```
//Classe Controladora
CollectionReference cr = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('parceiros').doc(identificador).collection("agendamento");
      print(cr.toString());
      await cr.snapshots().listen((snapshot) async {
        print("ENTROU NO ASYNC");
        for(int i=0;i<snapshot.size;i++){

          if (snapshot.docs[i].exists) { 
            //print("AG" +snapshot.docs[i].data()["agendamento"].toString());

            listAgendamentos.add(Agendamento.fromMap(snapshot.docs[i].data()["agendamento"]));
            print(listAgendamentos.elementAt(i));
            //Map data = await snapshot.docs[i].data()["clientes"];

          }

        }

        print("lista agendamentos tamanho no retorno ${listAgendamentos.length} ${DateTime.now().toString()}");
        print("RETORNOU A LISTA NUVEM");


      });

      return  listAgendamentos;
```

Abaixo um trecho minha função que consome o retorno do firestore.
PS: Eu usei o Delayed somente pra teste, ele será retirado.

```
//Classe Consumidora
await helper.getTodosAgendamentos().then((listaAgendamentos)=> agendamentoObject=listaAgendamentos);

        //print(agendamentoObject.toString());

    new Future.delayed(new Duration(milliseconds: 100), (){
      print("agendamentos OBJECTO tamanho "+agendamentoObject.length.toString());

      marcacoes.add(DecorationItem(
          decorationAlignment: FractionalOffset.bottomRight,
          date: DateTime.now(),
          decoration: Icon(
            Icons.today,
            color: Colors.blue,
          )));

      for(i=0;i<agendamentoObject.length;i++){
        print("ID "+agendamentoObject[i].idAgendamento.toString());

        int horas = parseDuration("${agendamentoObject[i].duracaoAgendamento}").inHours;
        int minutos = parseDuration("${agendamentoObject[i].duracaoAgendamento}").inMinutes-(60*horas);
        DateTime dataAgendada = DateTime.parse("${agendamentoObject[i].dataAgendamento}");
        DateTime fimAgendamento = dataAgendada.add( Duration(hours: horas,minutes:minutos ));
        String nomeDoCliente = "${agendamentoObject[i].clienteAgendamento}";
        String procedimento = "${agendamentoObject[i].procedimentoAgendamento}";
        String observacao = "${agendamentoObject[i].observacaoAgendamento}";
        int idAgend = agendamentoObject[i].idAgendamento;
        String whatsapp = "${agendamentoObject[i].whatsappAgendamento}";


        marcacoes.add(DecorationItem(
            date: dataAgendada,
            decoration: Text(
              'Agendamento',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.brown,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
              ),
            )
        ));


        events.add(FlutterWeekViewEvent(
          title: nomeDoCliente,
          start: dataAgendada,
          end: fimAgendamento,
          description: procedimento,
          onTap: (){
            editaEvento(context,idAgend,nomeDoCliente,procedimento,dataAgendada,fimAgendamento,observacao,whatsapp);
          },
        ));
      }
    });
```

Com o delayed confirmei o que já sabia, o código posterior ta sendo executado antes do retorno da função.

O que eu gostaria de fazer através da função assíncrona e o uso do await era que o código posterior esperasse a execução e o retorno da lista do getTodosAgendamentos() e só depois disso continuasse a execução.
Peço desculpas, na postagem a identação ficou meio torta, mas acredito que esteja legível.

**Resumindo meu problema**
Quando chega nesse trecho
`await cr.snapshots().listen((snapshot) async {...}`
A classe consumidora continua a execução sem a controladora ter finalizado e retornado a lista, assim não ocorre o preenchimento dos widgets
Porque isso acontece? Alguma sugestão de como resolver?

Comment: Pessoal da negativação, poderiam por favor explicar qual é o problema com minha pergunta?  Expliquei o que fiz e  mostrei o que resolveu parcialmente, fiz uma explicação longa e uma resumida da dúvida, agradeceria se comentasse qual é o problema para eu não repetir, ao invés de só apertar um botão de negativar. :)

Comment: Aconselho você buscar entender melhor como funciona as funções síncronas e assíncronas em Flutter... Você não está sabendo lidar com isso, ao utilizar o `await` você não precisa utilizar o `then` e vice-versa... Você está tentando aguardar um `listen`, sendo que o mesmo é para ficar "ouvindo", logo não é para utilizar o `await`... Da uma lida aqui nessa minha [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/447627/87785) para entender um pouco mais.

Comment: Matheus, muito obrigado pela sua resposta.
Você apontou um erro que eu não tinha notado. 

Na verdade eu já tinha lido sobre Async Await e then/WhenComplete, a questão do listener é que por questão de organização eu queria manter o código fora da classe que consome o widget, mas para descomplicar minha vida, criei a função dentro da própria classe passando o snapshot na construção dos widgets.