# Retorna repetido em ação na tela de login do flutter

Tags: api, flutter, login

```dart
  bool _login;
  Future<bool> login(String email, String senha) async {
    var response = await http.get("http://192.168.0.116:5001/usuarios/login/$email/$senha");
    if(response.statusCode == 200) {
      return _login = true;
    } else {
      return _login = false;
    } 
  }
```

Botão:

```dart
    RaisedButton(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
      ),
      color: HotelAppTheme.buildLightTheme().primaryColor,
      onPressed: () {
        logar();
        _login == true ? print('s') : print('n');
 
      },
      child: Text('Entrar', style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: SizeConfig.of(context).dynamicScaleSize(size: 18),
        color: Colors.white
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Se insiro um email e senha válido e clico no botão, tenho como retorno `"s"`, até aqui tudo funcionando como esperado, entretanto, se altero e coloco um email ou senha inválido, e clico no botão novamente, o retorna ainda é `"s"`, mas se clico novamente no botão, o retorna muda para `"n"` como esperado. Por que na primeira ação ele não atualiza?

Agradeço a quem puder me ajudar.

Comment: Você pode dar uma olhada aqui nessa minha resposta sobre [async x await x Future](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/447627/87785) para entender um pouquinho mais sobre funções assíncronas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Torne a função `onPressed` do botão também assíncrona, e aguarde a conclusão da função de login:

```
[...]
onPressed: () async {
                    await logar();
                    _login == true ? print('s') : print('n');
             
                  }
[...]
```

Como você não utilizou o `await`, a função `onPressed` não esperará o retorno do get, portanto utilizando o valor da variável `_login` errado.

Para maior aprendizado sobre chamadas assíncronas e a palavra chave `await`, experimente [este](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await) guia (em inglês), ou pesquise outras perguntas por aqui na rede mesmo.

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Comment: De nada! Se a resposta lhe agradou, não esqueça de marcá-la como aceita para ajudar eventuais buscas no site.